# Group pivot dataframe date columns to month and year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, data-analysis

I have a pandas pivot dataframe. Below is the dataframe.

This is my code:

```
pivot = df.query('brand_name == "ishin"').pivot_table(index = "channel_name",
                                                columns = "order_date",
                                                values = "qty",
                                                aggfunc = "sum",
                                                fill_value= 0,
                                                margins = False)
```

Below image is the output of the dataframe:

[image]

I want to group the date outputs to month and year. Example: all the April month outputs will be grouped as April-2023. All outputs except the current month outputs should be grouped. How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to use groupby but how can I exclude current month?

Comment: 1. Please provide sample data and in a [minimal and reproducible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391). Otherwise people won't be able to test. 2. Please also show the expected output explicitly.

Comment: Please don't use images of data, provide a [mre] of the input and the matching expected output.

Comment: Also, clarify what should happen to the current month (dropped?)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a `Year-month` column and do exactly what you did:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    'brand_name': ['ishin', 'ishin', 'ishin', 'other', 'ishin', 'ishin'],
    'channel_name': ['online', 'offline', 'online', 'online', 'offline', 'offline'],
    'order_date': pd.to_datetime(['2023-04-01', '2023-04-15', '2023-05-02', '2023-05-10', '2023-06-25', '2023-06-26']),
    'qty': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_date'])
df['year_month'] = df['order_date'].dt.to_period('M')
current_year_month = pd.to_datetime('now').to_period('M')
filtered_df = df.query('brand_name == "ishin" & year_month != @current_year_month')

pivot = filtered_df.pivot_table(index="channel_name",
                                 columns="year_month",
                                 values="qty",
                                 aggfunc="sum",
                                 fill_value=0)

pivot.columns = pivot.columns.astype(str)

pivot
```

which gives you

```
year_month    2023-04  2023-05  2023-06
channel_name                           
offline            20        0      110
online             10       30        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformat your dates to monthly periods before pivoting ([`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)), then convert the column format to `'%B %Y'` with [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html), and [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the current month based on today's date:

```
out = (df
 .assign(order_date=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d['order_date']).dt.to_period('M'))
 .pivot_table(index='channel_name',
              columns='order_date',
              values='qty',
              aggfunc='sum',
              fill_value=0,
              margins=False)
 .rename(columns=lambda x: x.strftime('%B %Y'))
 .drop(columns=pd.Timestamp('today').strftime('%B %Y'))
)
```

Example output:

```
order_date    April 2023  May 2023  June 2023  July 2023  August 2023  \
channel_name                                                            
A                   2044      1603       2236       2560         2821   
B                   2034      2737       2346       2581         1490   
C                   2291      1982       2263       3106         1815   

order_date    September 2023  October 2023  November 2023  December 2023  \
channel_name                                                               
A                       2159          2039           2021           2134   
B                       1542          1613           2579           2530   
C                       2787          2797           2934           2404   

order_date    January 2024  
channel_name                
A                     2468  
B                     2484  
C                     1983
```

Reproducible example input:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

dates = pd.date_range('2023-04-01', '2024-02-29', freq='D')
df = (pd.DataFrame(product(['A', 'B', 'C'], dates),
                   columns=['channel_name', 'order_date'])
        .sample(frac=1.5, replace=True, ignore_index=True)
        .assign(qty=lambda d: np.random.randint(0, 100, size=len(d)))
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but can you please help me to know how can I keep march month data in days not group them by month?